# MySQL - Plain index vs Fulltext

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search, fulltext-index

Based on the following simplified table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Lexicon (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    term VARCHAR(100),
    entry TEXT,
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

How would you query the database for things like *terms that are not present in their entries*? Or *terms that are not present in any of the entries*?

I was thinking of utilising a `FULLTEXT INDEX on Lexicon(entry)` but the `AGAINST()` part of the `MATCH()` query wouldn't allow me to pass any bindings.

```sql
SELECT term FROM Lexicon 
WHERE NOT MATCH(entry) AGAINST('only-literals-allowed-here' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

So, are fulltext indices somehow usable in these kind of scenarios or a plain index with a regular pattern matching query would be the only way to go?

For example (check against own entry):

```sql
SELECT term FROM Lexicon
WHERE entry NOT LIKE CONCAT ('%', term, '%');
```

or the even more monstrous (check against all the entries on the table):

```sql
SELECT LexiconB.term FROM Lexicon as LexiconA
JOIN Lexicon as LexiconB ON LexiconA.entry NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', LexiconB.term, '%')
GROUP BY LexiconB.term
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT count(*) FROM Lexicon);
```

Comment: `WHERE entry NOT LIKE CONCAT ('%', term, '%')` is very inefficient. Don't do this for tables with millions of rows.

Comment: Yeah, I can only imagine the pattern matching would be terrible even with an index available. Any better ideas?

Comment: I think you are stuck with `NOT LIKE` -- the first one, not the monstrous one.